# Spacing out outputs in ListBox

Tags: c#, spacing

I'm having trouble spacing out each item displayed in my listbox, they are too close together.
I've tried the code below & also tried just "" instead of "\t" but my third value disappears when I do either.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //clear any previous values
        listBox3.Items.Clear();
        for (int index = 0; index < currentCapacity; index++)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(string.Format("{0, -10}{1, 10}{2, 10}", 
           name[index],"\t", numTickets[index],"\t", costs[index]));
        }
     }
```

Comment: Use a datagridview?

Comment: Or a ListView. It's like a ListBox but with Columns. Plus some more features that you may find interesting.

Answer (score 0):

so you can concatenate your items with space/tap instead of adding them as an items

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //clear any previous values
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    for (int index = 0; index < currentCapacity; index++)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Add(string.Format("{0, -10}{1, 10}{2, 10}", 
       name[index] + "\t", numTickets[index] + "\t", costs[index]));
    }
}
```